# GET API Information in PHP for nearest famoust places of all types

Tags: php

I just want to integrate api in my php project, which gives result in json or in xml form for nearest all type of famous places like restaurants, parks, showrooms, malls etc.

Please let me know if u guys have any idea.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

API of foursquare?

https://developer.foursquare.com/

Google Places API:

https://developers.google.com/places/

EDIT:
There is a database with API's, maybe you can find something there? http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory

Comment: Thank you for your reply Finduilas, but i already have searched for this api, but the client don't want to use this. so, i have to find another one.

Comment: I don't want to search particular place, i just want an api which searches nearest all famous places.any type of places.

Comment: I think you have to take a look to it.. With places you can look for stores, restaurants,... See example for stores: 

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search